# Is it possible for scrapy to navigate links before actually scraping data?

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been working through a few scrapy tutorials and I have a question (I'm very new to this, so I apologize if this is a dumb question). Most of what I've seen so far involved:

1) feeding a starting url to scrapy

2) telling scrapy what parts of the page to grab

3) telling scrapy how to find the "next" page to scrape from

What I'm wondering is - am I able to scrape data using scrapy when the data itself isn't on the start page? For example, I have a link that goes to a forum. The forum contains links to several subforums. Each subforum has links to several threads. Each thread contains several messages (possibly over multiple pages). The messages are what I ultimately want to scrape. Is it possible to do this and use only the initial link to the forum? Is it possible for scrapy to navigate through every subforum, and every thread and *then* start scraping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can navigate without scraping data, though you will need to extract the links for navigation with either `xpath` or `css` or `CrawlSpider` rules. These links can be used just for navigation and don't need to be loaded into items.

There's no requirement that you load something into an item from every page you visit. Consider a scenario where you need to authenticate past login to get to data that you want to scrape. No need to scrape/pipeline/write any data from the login page.

For your purposes:

```
def start_requests(self):
    forum_url = <spam>
    yield scrapy.Request(url=forum_url, callback=self.parse_forum)

def parse_forum(self, response):
    #get the urls
    for u in subforum_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=u, callback=parse_subforum)

def parse_subforum(self, response):
    #get the other urls
    for u in thread_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=u, callback=parse_thread)

def parse_thread(self, response):
    #get the data you want
    yield <the data>
```